# How to change label spacing and position for OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

#### Is there a way to set the position of the label and increase the spacing

(UI of the TextField should look like this):
[image]

```kotlin
   OutlinedTextField(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        singleLine = true,
        label = {
            Text(
                text = "Test Hint",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
            )
        }
    )
```

I have tried increasing the spacing of label using padding. It works but I cannot move the position of the label, using offset or padding:

[image]

Comment: Or I need to implement custom solution using BasicTextField

Comment: have you tried to put Text inside a Row and add a Spacer on side of Text?

Comment: Yep it does not work

Comment: I can not say that I understood your question. 
judging by pictures it seems you want to move label more into the end and have longer border in the start.

Im afraid to say you must implement completely new TextField from scratch